# Avoid ClassCastException in Generic Factory method

Tags: java, oop, generics, design-patterns

I have an abstract class A. Few more abstract classes which extends A, say B, C. Now I have some concrete classes which extends B, C. So the situation looks like:

```
abstract class A;
abstract class B extends A;
abstract class C extends A;
class B1 extends B;
class B2 extends B;
class C1 extends C;
class C2 extends C;
```

B1, B2, C1, C2 are links in [chain of responsibility pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) and they have to be in an order. So, I have an enumeration which defines the order. It looks like:

```
Enum Order {
  B_ORDER    (B1.class, B2.class),
  C_ORDER    (C1.class, C2.class);

  Class<? extends A>[] chainOrder;
}
```

I've a factory method which would initialize this chain. It takes chainOrder and Type as input and returns the head of the chain of the same type.

```
<T extends A> T createChain(Class<? extends A>[] chainOrder, Class<? extends A> chainType) {
  // Test if all the classes in chainOrder is of same type given by chainType
  // Do some other stuff
}
```

The question is can I avoid the type checking in the factory (i.e. can it be taken care at compile time) ?

If not, what is the correct way to ensure that a chain contains links of the same type.

Any other design suggestion is also welcome.

PS: We are in JDK 1.7

Comment: Could you give a little more detail of your problem? For example, you ask "what is the correct way to ensure that a chain contains links of the same type", but it'd be fixed just by a ``createChain`` for each type, thus using Java static typing. I think your problem might be you're not hiding the complexity of the creation behind an specific factory method but using a unnecesary parameter (``chainOrder``), but I might've not understood the issue.

Comment: is the second parameter of createChain a Order. `<T extends A> T createChain(Class<? extends A>[] chainOrder, Order chainType)`

Comment: @طاهر No. First parameter is the order and second parameter is the type (if its of type B or type C). The order is defined in the enum but there is no type check since it'll accept everything that qualifies Class<? extends A>[]. So the problem is enum entry of link order is not guarded for the specific type (B or C) so createChain has to guarantee if its not instantiating a wrong type in a chain.

Comment: @juanignaciosl Problem- the order of the nodes that is defined for every type namely B and C are not able to make sure that this list contains all elements of same type. So, createChain has additional responsibility to check if every node in the order list passed is of same type. So, in this scenario the problem is- enum value B_ORDER might also contain C1.class or C2.class. And you are correct- we are not hiding the complexity of chain creation behind specific factory because there is no difference in chain creation of two types and we want code reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add one `createChain` for `B` and `C`:

```
<T extends A> T createChain(Class<? extends B>[] chainOrder)
<T extends A> T createChain(Class<? extends C>[] chainOrder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is createChain doesn't do anything different for these two types and we want to reuse the code. Hence the additional parameter chainType is passed to have the chain of specific type. So createChain has to check that the every class in the chain order passed is the correct type (passed as the other parameter chainType).

Comment: Ok, understood. I think this is response is fine. First of all, you don't always need your duplication refactors to leak your API. You should certainly expose different methods for different types instead of passing a class around. If this were Scala maybe using a class parameter would be better, but this response is certainly the Java way. If you don't want to repeat, these public methods can invoke a private one, and since you're sure typesare correct (since calls conforms restricted, public API) you don't need additional typechecking.

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. I was little hesitant initially but looks like Factory is the only and correct way.